# Android List View Row margins

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I was trying to create a simple list view that has some padding for each row.

I did it in a really simple way, but I'm not sure if it is the right™ way to do it.

This is what I got (code is below). As you can see when you tap a row, it is fully highlighted, and I want (if possible) to highlight only the view inside it (the one with the gray background, that is a TextView)

[image: Example]

this is the code for the Activity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/no_events" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and this is the code of the list item layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="#ccc"
        android:text="placeholder" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Thanks for any reply!

PS. I didn't upload the Activity, it is a simple ListActivity.

**UPDATE**

Resolved (thanks to Jorge Aguilar). The new code is this:

List item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/event_focused"
        android:text="placeholder" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Event focused file (which is in the drawable directory):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@android:color/black" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@android:color/darker_gray" /> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:state_hovered="true"
          android:drawable="@android:color/darker_gray" /> <!-- hovered -->
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/darker_gray" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

I also added this:

```
android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
```

to my ListView :)

Comment: Have you tried to set margin or padding to the ListView instead of?

Comment: yep, but I got the scroll bar inside the listview: http://i.imgur.com/PsW5I.png and I don't like it :)

Comment: I guess you could set top and bottom margin to the ListView and right and left one to list view items (FrameLayout)

Comment: I didn't try it yet, but I think that the problem still remains, at lest for left and right margin :)

Comment: Well, my last try would be... change cache color hint and list selector colors, like: `android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" ` or if does't work you can always override Widget.ListView style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you can add on the onitemselected method some code to find the textview by id or something similar and then change the background color. or is something different what you want ?

**UPDATE:**

If you need to change it from within the xml file, maybe this **[post](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/Qk_cWEzxmuo)** can help you achieve it. just skip to the last post and hopefully you will find your answer there.

Comment: this is a solution, but I want to know if there is a way to it directly in the layout files :) Thanks by the way!

Comment: i already updated my answer, if that helps you mark it as answer so if anyone is in need of the same thing, they can know how to do it.